# Manejo de la libreria jit.js con json

Tags: javascript, json

Mirad, tengo un fichero `.js` que carga un `json` y está funcionando. En principio se le carga un `json` completo, y luego al hacer `click` expande los hijos del nodo clickado:

- Cuando se carga la página:

  ```
  //load json data
  st.loadJSON(json);
  //compute node positions and layout
  st.compute();
  //optional: make a translation of the tree
  st.geom.translate(new $jit.Complex(-200, 0), "current");
  //emulate a click on the root node.
  st.onClick(st.root);
  //end
  ```
- Cuando se hace un `click` en el nodo:

  ```
  onCreateLabel: function(label, node){
      label.id = node.id;            
      label.innerHTML = node.name;
      label.onclick = function(){
          st.onClick(node.id);
      };
  ```

He introducido una modificación , para que al principio se cargue un `json` y después otro más grande al hacer click en un nodo:

```
 onCreateLabel: function(label, node){
        label.id = node.id;            
        label.innerHTML = node.name;
        label.onclick = function(){

        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "inicio_pru.php";
        var params = "callFunction=arbol_completo";
        http.open("POST", url, true);
        //Send the proper header information along with the request
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.send(params);
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
                    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {

                             json=http.responseText;
                             st.loadJSON(json);
                              //compute node positions and layout
                             st.compute();
                              //optional: make a translation of the tree
                             st.geom.translate(new $jit.Complex(-200, 0), "current");
                             //emulate a click on the root node.
                             st.onClick(node.id);
                      }
            };
```

La carga de la página va correcta, pero al clickar en el label de un nodo, me da el siguiente error:

> jit.js:8795 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

El json es asi:

```
'{"id":"38358","name":"Anillo Critico","data":{"$color":"#008000","$type":"circle"},"children":[]}';
```

Con lo que deduzco que al hacer `st.loadJSON(json)`, se crea un node con un `id`, un `name` y un `data`, y se crea uno por cada `id` del `json`. Cuando hago `click` en uno, le mando a `st.onClick(node.id)` el `node.id` de ese en concreto.

¿Me podéis ayudar? Muchisimas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Imagino que habrá sido un error al 'copypastear', pero en el método `onCreateLabel()` falta una llave de cierre. No puedo editar el código, por alguna extraña razón no me pilla el formato..

Comment: Gracias @Mariano!

Comment: Si , efectivamente, Mariano , en el código está con la llave. Estoy casi convencida que dentro del 'onreadystatechange' , no tiene acceso al objeto 'st' , porque fuera de ella. sí lo coge.Si hago esto fuera: st.loadJSON(json); , sí lo coge, pero no el de la función onreadystatechange , sino el anterior que ya tenía.Necesitaría cargarle fuera de ésta función el json de la función onreadystatechange